# How can i use linq for parsing string datetime to real datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

my ExpiryDate is "10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM" means MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM but it is string from SAP. How can i convert it MM/dd/YYYY
below codes not working.error :

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How can i do that by using linq?

```
var query = deliveriesItemsbypaging.Select(tb => tb.ExpiryDate)
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing locally
              .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Split(new char[0])[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

this blog  code is working :

```
 var r =   DateTime.ParseExact("10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM".Split(new char[0])[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Why you not using correct format ? like : `DateTime.ParseExact("10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Your code seems ok to me. Check the values in your `ExpiryDate`,maybe you have any incorrect value

Comment: What is the data type of `ExpiryDate`? Why isn't it a `DateTime` in the database itself? Storing dates as strings is a *very serious* bug. Instead of trying to parse the data, just fix the database schema

Comment: Generally problem is : "7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM" when it happened

Comment: "7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM" wouldn't be parsed with "MM/dd/yyyy". It expects 2 digits for the month.

Comment: What i meant: just replace "MM/dd/yyyy" with "M/dd/yyyy" and it should work. Anyway, as @PanagiotisKanavos said, Dates should be stored with its own type not as a string

Comment: @Penguen what is the column's type? Why is it string instead of `DateTime`? Have you actually stored the date as a string, or did you convert the date to a string while loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Parse` here

```
var query = deliveriesItemsbypaging.Select(tb => tb.ExpiryDate)
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing locally
              .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date);
```

`.Date` here will give you date only without time, as you need.

UPDATE: 
If you want to get an enumerable of strings (in specific format), you might want to rewrite it as

```
var query = deliveriesItemsbypaging.Select(tb => tb.ExpiryDate)
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing locally
              .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/YYYY"));
```

Comment: This will retun a Date time object which then needs still to be converted into string.

Comment: use DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") or even simpler, DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 3):

Use specific string  format when You using `DateTime.ParseExact()`, you need use 
`"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"` format ,next use `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

```
List<string> dateTimes = new List<string>();
dateTimes.Add("10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM");
var selectValue = dateTimes.Select(d => d)
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).ToList();

var r = DateTime.ParseExact("10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
var query = deliveriesItemsbypaging.Select(tb => tb.ExpiryDate)
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing locally
              .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Split(new char[]{' '})[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: OP's code should works also because he is passing an empty `char[]` which uses all white-space characters as delimiters then. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx): _"Each element of separator defines a separate delimiter that consists of a single character. If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters."_. So your approach is a subset of OP's.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = deliveriesItemsbypaging
    .Select(tb => tb.ExpiryDate)
    .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the processing locally
    .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below method can convert MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM format dates to convertable string date

```
    string DateConverter(string date)
    {
        string[] dmy= date.Split(' ')[0].Split('/');
        string convertedDay = dmy[1] + "/" + dmy[0] + "/" + dmy[2];
        return convertedDay;
    }
```